# How do I add cells in google sheets to make a total specifically using previous entries?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm not sure how to word this, but im creating a pilot episode for a film I'm making and I am not sure what function(s) to do so that when I add a duration to a specicfic shot, it updates a row down and a column right to it (adding to the time stamp of the episode). Anybody have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## SCAN Formula

Make sure the number format for all relevant columns is set to `Duration` and place the following formula in B2.

```
={0; (SCAN(0,TOCOL(A2:A,1), 
   LAMBDA(s, n, s+n)))}
```

- The SCAN function is perfect for this task.  It returns the intermediary calculations from a LAMBDA function that adds `s` an accumulator (subtotal) to `n` a new number.
- variable names are arbitrary, use whatever you prefer.
- TOCOL  is used because it can remove empty rows.  In this way, the entire column A can be specified as the range allowing the formula to expand dynamically as new data is added.
- An initial duration of `0` is added to the array to offset it because you want starting, not ending, timestamps.

[image: A table showing initial durations, formula, and starting timestamps]

## Both Starting and Ending Timestamps

The formula can be easily adapted to return a two-column array of starting and ending timestamps in a single formula, since it is essentially the same formula, simply offset by one row:

```
=LET(end,SCAN(0,TOCOL(A2:A,1), 
   LAMBDA(s, n, s+n)),
   {{0;end},{end;""}})
```

- LET is used to store the result of

  ```
  SCAN(0,TOCOL(A2:A,1), 
     LAMBDA(s, n, s+n))
  ```

  in the variable `end`
- an array is returned where

  - column 1 is `end` with a `0` prepended as the first row
  - column 2 is `end` with a blank value appended as the last row

[image: table showing initial durations, formula, and starting and ending timestamps]

## Functions

[LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) [SCAN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094?hl=en) [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `= P3 + P4` in the Q4 should work. Q3 doesn't need a formula; it'll just be 0:00:00. Just drag down the formula by the bottom-right square and it'll add it up for you.